# TinyMCE: How to prevent <br>-TAG in list-element

Tags: javascript, html, css, tinymce

I have an tinyMCE and I have to set the option "force_br_newlines: true", because when I don't do it, and I'm pushing "Enter" for example two times and look in the source-code, there is only one `<br>`.

But when I set the option on TRUE, I have a problem with my unsorted list. When the loaded text comes from my databse to the tinyMCE, it makes out of

`<ul><li> MY TEXT </li><li> MY TEXT 2 </li><ul>`

this-->

`<ul><br /><li> MY TEXT </li><br /><li> MY TEXT 2 </li><br /><ul>`

Is there a possibility to prevent this??? I dont want to have the `<br />` in it!
THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR YOUR HELP!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

> BR elements should only be used when you really have to (mostly
>   never). Also as of 3.x the forced_root_block option is enabled by
>   default so if you really want to disable paragraphs disable that one
>   as well.

So add

```
tinyMCE.init({
        ...
        force_br_newlines : true,
        force_p_newlines : false,
        forced_root_block : '' // Needed for 3.x
});
```

BTW [TinyMCE's official page](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:force_br_newlines) suggests not to use BR elements for linebreaks.

Comment: But then the problem ist, when I have a text and I want to make TWO breaks, I push 2-Times-Return, but when I loom in the Source-Code, there is only ONE Break. The two BREAKS are only shown in the editor. So when I save it, and relaod it in the tinymce, there is only one BREAK!

Comment: That's because the cleaning is enabled in TinyMCE, you can disable it by `cleanup : false`. http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:cleanup

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
tinyMCE.init {
    ...
    ...
    apply_source_formatting : false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you include 'lists' in plugins settings?

```js
tinymce.init({
    plugins: "lists link stylebuttons", // For example
    // ...
});
```